# Yii return all records with common tags

Tags: php, yii, tags

i'm writing a documentation centre in Yii. I have it all working apart from one section, where i want to pull related articles. Note: i don't mean related as relational databases, purely, using the term.

So when i'm on the article view, i want to be able to pull a table below the article that lists other articles with a common tag. Each record in the articles database has a column with comma separated values in it.

i.e.

```
id | title | tags
1  | new   | new,article,text
2  | new2  | new,alternate
3  | new3  | new,test,text
```

So i need to pass my records `$model->tags` into a function that outputs a model with only records that contains for example the tag `new`

Here's what i have so far, though i can't even think how to get this to work;

```
public function getRelatedArticles($category) {
    $search_array = explode(",", $category)
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();

    $criteria->compare('tags', $category);

    return DocsArticles::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```

Has anyone done this before or know's how it can be done?

Answer (score 1):

I assume your *tags* field are using string, each tag separated by coma.

You can use *addCondition* method in *CDbCriteria*. As for search criteria, I will use either for string **,new** or **new,**

Here is an example:

```
public function getRelatedArticles($category) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
    $criteria->addCondition("tags LIKE '%,{$category}%' OR tags LIKE '%{$category},%'");
    return DocsArticles::model()->findAll($criteria);
}
```

But there is a little problem with this, if your *tags* field only has 1 tag value like 'new', it won't work. For this you may need to create user defined function in your database.

Hope this help.

Edit:

The string in the database remain same, nothing to change. Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll have a go and see if I can get this to work

Comment: so just now the values in my tag column are i.e" new,test,five ", are you suggesting they need to be strings i.e. " 'new','test','five' "?

Comment: no, it is fine as it is, leave the data. the string with quote in addCondition is what required just for sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer zmiftah, took me a while to implement it, but your answer was 90% there. The issue with the answer was the $category variable contains the string " new,test,five ", the item that needs to be wrapped in the sql wildcards needs to be the individual array item.

Here's my code;

```
public function getRelatedArticles($category,$id) {
        $array = explode(',',$category);
        $tagItems = null;
        foreach($array as $tag){
            $tagItems[0] = "id !={$id} AND (tags LIKE '%{$tag}%'";
            $tagItems[] = "OR tags LIKE '%{$tag}%'";
        }
        $arrayReturn = implode(" ",$tagItems);
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->addCondition($arrayReturn . ")");
        return DocsArticles::model()->findAll($criteria);
    }
```

This code is also doing a couple of other things to, like removing the existing id from the returning model, so i'm not pulling the article i've just read as related. Thanks for your help.